# How to create a dynamic SelectBox from a model field that is declared as CharField in django

Tags: python, django

In my knowledge foreignkey and manytomany model fields are allowed to display as dropdown boxes. But i am in need of to declare my Author field as CharField in Model. Display this field as dynamic Author SelectBox from model in ModelForm. Is there any possiblity for this in django? or do I need to do Custom Form Field for dynamic Selection?

```
Author = models.CharField('Author',blank=True, null=True, help_text='Enter Author')
```

Comment: well, why don't you do that?

Comment: Please add more details to what you want and what you've tried so far. How and where are you storing the data for the dropdown list that you want, etc.

Comment: Also, how dynamic is the list? Fetch the list items in the `view` and send it to the html page from django and load it there. Or, use ajax to fetch the data and load it.

Comment: Sorry it is a dropdown box not a list. i am declared author field as charfield in model, but i want to display this field as dropdown box to collect authors data from database

Comment: So I'm still not sure what your question is. Why can't you display the values in a "dropdown box"?